# Why is $f(e)=1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative complex Banach Algebra with unit element $e$. Now, let $f \in A^*$ be a non-zero multiplicative linear functional.

Why does it follow, directly from the above, that $f(e)=1$?

Comment: It has the exact same two-line proof that if $g$ is a group homomorphism, then $g$ takes the identity to either zero or the identity. Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $e^2=e$, $f(e)^2=f(e)$.  This means $f(e)$ must be either $0$ or $1$.  But if $f(e)=0$, then $f(x)=f(ex)=f(e)f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$.